# Android program crash after first statement

Tags: android

I have an Android app. I use Android Studio. This app was working before I added code unrelated to the crash location. I place breakpoints on the first few lines. When I start the debugger properly stops on the first two lines but crashes before getting to the next statement. Since this part of the code has not changed I don't have a clue as to why it would crash. Can someone suggest something to look for?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    // Set up the login form.
    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    populateAutoComplete();
```

Here is the XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              tools:context="com.mynt.mynt.LoginActivity">

    <!-- Login progress -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/email"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id = "@+id/EDITTEXT"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:ellipsize = "end"
                    android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:scrollbars = 'vertical'
                    android:text = ""/>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the output from Android Monitor:

```
02-13 11:53:31.150 17373-17373/? E/Zygote: v2
02-13 11:53:31.150 17373-17373/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10380
02-13 11:53:31.150 17373-17373/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
02-13 11:53:31.160 17373-17373/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], SPD-policy is existed. and_ver=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1 ver=11
02-13 11:53:31.160 17373-17373/? W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0030
02-13 11:53:31.160 17373-17373/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
02-13 11:53:31.160 17373-17373/? W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=com.mynt.mynt 
02-13 11:53:31.160 17373-17373/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-13 11:53:31.180 17373-17373/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
02-13 11:53:31.180 17373-17373/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
02-13 11:53:31.210 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.mynt.mynt-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.mynt.mynt rsrc of package com.mynt.mynt
02-13 11:53:31.210 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath + mLibMap{0=, 1=}
02-13 11:53:31.210 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
02-13 11:53:31.220 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt W/ActivityThread: Application com.mynt.mynt is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
02-13 11:53:31.220 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
02-13 11:53:31.390 17373-17379/com.mynt.mynt I/art: Debugger is active
02-13 11:53:31.420 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/System.out: Debugger has connected
02-13 11:53:31.420 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 11:53:31.620 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 11:53:31.820 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 11:53:32.020 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 11:53:32.220 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 11:53:32.420 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 11:53:32.620 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 11:53:32.820 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
02-13 11:53:33.020 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/System.out: debugger has settled (1467)
02-13 11:53:33.020 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/InjectionManager: Inside getClassLibPath caller 
02-13 11:53:33.020 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.mynt.mynt-1/lib/arm64
02-13 11:53:33.030 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.mynt.mynt, real application class is null.
02-13 11:53:33.420 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.mynt.mynt-1/lib/arm64
02-13 11:53:33.420 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt D/InjectionManager: InjectionManager
02-13 11:53:33.420 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt D/InjectionManager: fillFeatureStoreMap com.mynt.mynt
02-13 11:53:33.420 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/InjectionManager: Constructor com.mynt.mynt, Feature store :{}
02-13 11:53:33.420 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/InjectionManager: featureStore :{}
02-13 11:53:33.790 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.mynt.mynt-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.mynt.mynt rsrc of package com.mynt.mynt
02-13 11:53:33.820 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt W/ResourcesManager: getTopLevelResources: /data/app/com.mynt.mynt-1/base.apk / 1.0 running in com.mynt.mynt rsrc of package com.mynt.mynt
02-13 11:53:41.640 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
02-13 11:53:46.280 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
02-13 11:53:46.520 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt I/TextInputLayout: EditText added is not a TextInputEditText. Please switch to using that class instead.
02-13 11:53:46.560 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-13 11:53:46.600 17373-17373/com.mynt.mynt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                               Process: com.mynt.mynt, PID: 17373
                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mynt.mynt/com.mynt.mynt.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #73: We already have an EditText, can only have one
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3254)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795)
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237)
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                                                                Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #73: We already have an EditText, can only have one
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288)
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                   at com.mynt.mynt.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:78)
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207)
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
                                                                Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: We already have an EditText, can only have one
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setEditText(TextInputLayout.java:320)
                                                                   at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.addView(TextInputLayout.java:283)
                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4462)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:856)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:855)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
                                                                   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:288) 
                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                   at com.mynt.mynt.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:78) 
                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876) 
                                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3207) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:222) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1795) 
                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7237) 
                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: show us your logcat

Comment: Paste your XML file and your logcat with the crash stracktrace for us to help you.

Comment: What's the error message? Are you perhaps missing the closing bracket at the end of the onCreate method?

Comment: We need to see the error logs - we can't debug a problem if we don't know what the problem is and "it crashed" is not a problem description.

Comment: I showed the logic. How do I get a stacktrace? I will paste the XML but I don't see how that will help. The error message is the standard crash message ... "unfortunately Mynt has stopped".  btw don't put someone down just because you can't help. I'm not asking anyone to debug the problem. I'm just asking how one would look for the problem (education).

Comment: Doesn't this line in your logcat `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #73: We already have an EditText, can only have one` tell you anything?

Comment: HI Eddy, could you accept my reply if helped you? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change the code with the following, making any instance of EditText enclosed into a single TextInputLayout, because you get the following stacktrace line:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #73: We already have an EditText, can only have one
>                                                                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id = "@+id/EDITTEXT"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:editable="false"
                    android:ellipsize = "end"
                    android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:scrollbars = 'vertical'
                    android:text = ""/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                    android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                    android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                    android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"/>
                  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. As i said, I am new at Android programming and have probably made stupid mistakes. I wrote Cisco's Transceiver Library for the Nexus 7000 and am an expert in those areas but really stupid when it comes to Java and XML.

Comment: there is no stupidity, but a learning curve that is really enjoyable, what you did in the past sums up in synergy, anyway if you like upvote me, and if it works you can also accept my reply. Hope it works, good luck

Comment: DELL broke my computer so i have to wait a few days for tjem to fix it